# Virtual Keyboard test isn't working with my Keyboard Wedge

Tags: c#, winforms, nunit

I've installed com0com so that I can write a NUnit test. Just in case there is a definition difference of Keyboard wedge a brief description of it is a piece of software that listens to a Serial communications device, reads any data sent to it (in my case formats it to ASCII data) then sends that to a Virtual keyboard. This code does work in production but we are required to now either document our code or have a unit test to prove how it is supposed to be used. so here is my test

```
    [Test()]
    public void WedgeSendsTextToVirtualKeyboardTest()
    {
        (var form = new Form())
        using(var sp = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM"+COMB, 115200))
        using (var wedge = new KeyboardWedgeConfiguration(WEDGE_KEY))
        {
            sp.Open();

            TextBox tb = SetupForm(form);
            TurnOnKeyboardWedge(wedge);
            form.Activate();
            form.Activated += (s, e) =>
                {
                    tb.Focus();
                };
            while (!tb.Focused) { }

            string str = "Hello World";
            sp.Write(str);

            //wait 1 second. This allows data to send, and pool in the wedge
            //the minimum wait time is 200ms. the string then gets put into bytes
            //and shipped off to a virtual keyboard where all the keys are pressed.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Expect(tb.Text, Is.EqualTo(str));

        }
    }
    private static TextBox SetupForm(Form form)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Name = "tb";
        tb.TabIndex = 0;
        tb.AcceptsReturn = true;
        tb.AcceptsTab = true;
        tb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        form.Controls.Add(tb);
        form.Show();
        return tb;
    }

    private static void TurnOnKeyboardWedge(KeyboardWedgeConfiguration wedge)
    {
        wedge.Port = COMA;
        wedge.PortForwardingEnabled = true;
        wedge.Baud = 115200;
        System.IO.Ports.SerialPort serialPort;

        wedge.StartRerouting();
        Assert.IsTrue(wedge.IsAlive(out serialPort));
        Assert.IsNotNull(serialPort);
    }
```

When the test runs, the form shows, no text is put in the textbox, then the test exits and the last assert fails (`Expect(tb.Text, Is.EqualTo(str));`) saying that tb.Text is string.Empty. I've tried a number of different tactics to get focus on that textbox (i'm assuming that is the problem atleast). At one time I made my sleep longer so that I had time to click on the textbox and type myself, and I couldn't click on the box (I'm assuming that is because of the sleep operation... which is also probably why my wedge can't type in there as well) so how can I fix this problem and make my test pass. Again this code does work in a production environment, so I am 100% convinced it is my test (and probably that sleep operation)

Comment: I think [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362858/how-to-properly-unit-test-calling-ui-method-on-another-thread) could help guide you. You could do a similar thing, move the form to it's own thread and also the serial port writing to another thread, then wait on them.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make my test pass with the help of this question [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1362858/1329396) (thank you so much Patrick Quirk). It is actually a minor variation to it. I'm not even sure if my solution is 100% correct, but when the form pops up the text is entered and my test passes. The solution was two part system. First I had to make a class that extends `Form` override the `Text` property, and listen for the `Activated` and `FormClosing` Events. On Form Closing I would set my text, and on Activated I told my `TextBox` to have the focus.

```
    private class WedgeForm : Form
    {
        public override string Text { get { return text; } set { text = value; } }

        string text = string.Empty;
        private TextBox tb;

        public WedgeForm()
        {
            InitializeControls();

            Activated += (s, e) => { tb.Focus(); };
            FormClosing += (s, e) => { this.Text = tb.Text; };
        }

        private void InitializeControls()
        {
            tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Name = "tb";
            tb.TabIndex = 0;
            tb.AcceptsReturn = true;
            tb.AcceptsTab = true;
            tb.Multiline = true;
            tb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.Controls.Add(tb);
        }
    }
```

then using the InvokeEx method that was provided in the other qustion/answer My test easy to setup

```
    [Test()]
    public void WedgeSendsTextToVirtualKeyboardTest()
    {
        using (var form = new WedgeForm())
        using (var wedge = new KeyboardWedgeConfiguration(WEDGE_KEY))
        {
            TurnOnKeyboardWedge(wedge);

            string actual = MakeWedgeWriteHelloWorld(form, wedge); ;
            string expected = "Hello World";

            Expect(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));
        }
    }

    private static string MakeWedgeWriteHelloWorld(WedgeForm form, KeyboardWedgeConfiguration wedge)
    {
        var uiThread = new Thread(() => Application.Run(form));
        uiThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        uiThread.Start();

        string actual = string.Empty;
        var thread = new Thread
            (
                () => actual = InvokeEx<Form, string>(form, f => f.Text)
            );

        using (var sp = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM" + COMB, 115200))
        {
            sp.Open();
            sp.Write("Hello World");
        }
        //wait 1 second. This allows data to send, and pool in the wedge
        //the minimum wait time is 200ms. the string then gets put into bytes
        //and shipped off to a virtual keyboard where all the keys are pressed.
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        InvokeEx<Form>(form, f => f.Close());
        thread.Start();
        uiThread.Join();
        thread.Join();

        return actual;
    }
```

One minor thing I have to remember when running this test is to not be clicking around because if that textbox loses focus I'm sunk. But the test is only 1second long.. I think I'll live.